# Selenium - python. how to capture network traffic's response

Tags: python, django, selenium, browser, traffic

I am using python Django to create a web app. 
i am using selenium to launch a headless browser(phantomjs) and making some clicks till i reach a particular page. 
I wish to capture network traffic and get the response of a particular network call. This network call actually holds a html doc as it's response.

Any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can get access to browser or chromedriver logs, they are slightly different when it comes to network responses. The browser log is called `performance` and the driver log is called `driver`. They return a json-like object, which you can parse to extract events with Network methods inside them:

```
{'level': 'INFO',
  'message': '{"message":{"method":"Page.frameStoppedLoading","params":{"frameId":"FB10764A3ABF7FFC83110C39C5F7BF77"}},"webview":"C2D13BD13CF743B6D0695B35E9CC935C"}',
  'timestamp': 1538607113832},
 {'level': 'INFO',
  'message': '{"message":{"method":"Page.frameDetached","params":{"frameId":"FB10764A3ABF7FFC83110C39C5F7BF77"}},"webview":"C2D13BD13CF743B6D0695B35E9CC935C"}',
  'timestamp': 1538607113838},
 {'level': 'INFO',
  'message': '{"message":{"method":"Network.requestWillBeSent","params":{"documentURL":"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52633697/selenium-python-how-to-capture-network-traffics-response","frameId":"C2D13BD13CF743B6D0695B35E9CC935C","hasUserGesture":false,"initiator":{"type":"other"},"loaderId":"5331BFDC4F466FCED920CFC9F033D2EC","request":{"headers":{"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":"1","User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36"},"initialPriority":"VeryHigh","method":"GET","mixedContentType":"none","referrerPolicy":"no-referrer-when-downgrade","url":"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52633697/selenium-python-how-to-capture-network-traffics-response"},"requestId":"5331BFDC4F466FCED920CFC9F033D2EC","timestamp":104499.729,"type":"Document","wallTime":1538607113.838206}},"webview":"C2D13BD13CF743B6D0695B35E9CC935C"}',
  'timestamp': 1538607113839},...}
```

You need to enable logging in `DesiredCapabilities` and then parse it using `JSON` module:

```
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
caps['goog:loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'ALL'}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps)
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52633697/selenium-python-how-to-capture-network-traffics-response')

def process_browser_log_entry(entry):
    response = json.loads(entry['message'])['message']
    return response

browser_log = driver.get_log('performance') 
events = [process_browser_log_entry(entry) for entry in browser_log]
events = [event for event in events if 'Network.response' in event['method']]
```

I don't know if you can get access to response data itself using this, but you can get a url of the response.

Another option is to use a library like [selenium-wire](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/).

**UPDATE 2020-10-07 ⬇**

As [@Roey B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/516013/roey-b) and [@Inactivist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1309774/inactivist) explain in the comments, you can access response body using [Network.getResponseBody](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-getResponseBody) command:

```
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.getResponseBody', {'requestId': events[0]["params"]["requestId"]})
```

Comment: Note: If you're having trouble getting the performance log to work on recent (~75+) chrome, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56536604/5368039.  Basically just change `loggingPrefs` to `goog:loggingPrefs`

Comment: to get the response data you can run this: `driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.getResponseBody', {'requestId': msg["message"]["params"]["requestId"]})`

Comment: @RoeyB what goes in `msg`?

Comment: @RoeyB, please help explain what does "msg" stand for here? Thanks!

Comment: `msg` is one of the parsed JSON log entries returned by `driver.get_log('performance')`

see also [selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.execute_cdp_cmd](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_cdp_cmd)

Comment: @JeremyWeirich why don't you just edit the answer?

Comment: Here's a working example to extract JSON requests: https://gist.github.com/lorey/079c5e178c9c9d3c30ad87df7f70491d

Comment: Can somone help me on how to do this with firefox browser?,

Comment: From Selenium 4.0 onward the library will support accessing devtools information. It's still in beta state though.

Comment: In selenium 4 you enable the logging like this:

`chrome_options.set_capability('goog:loggingPrefs', {'performance': 'ALL'})`