# View list of element sources with Selenium?

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html5-canvas

I'd like to make an if/then statement with Python in Selenium webdriver to check if audio is being played. I know that with inspect element I'm able to see the list of data sources, and a new data sources is created / shown anytime audio is playing. Here is an example image of that below. How can I use Selenium to detect for this? *By data source, I don't mean HTML, but where the actual data is coming from

[Chrome inspect element image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRPGa.png)

Answer (score 0):

The browser or chromedriver logs contain The network responses.... among many other things sometimes. The Browser log is called `perfomance` And the driver log is called `driver`. They return a json-like object, which you can parse to extract events with Network methods inside them:

```
{'level': 'INFO',
  'message': '{"message":{"method":"Page.frameStoppedLoading","params":{"frameId":"FB10764A3ABF7FFC83110C39C5F7BF77"}},"webview":"C2D13BD13CF743B6D0695B35E9CC935C"}',
  'timestamp': 1538607113832},
 {'level': 'INFO',
  'message': '{"message":{"method":"Page.frameDetached","params":{"frameId":"FB10764A3ABF7FFC83110C39C5F7BF77"}},"webview":"C2D13BD13CF743B6D0695B35E9CC935C"}',
  'timestamp': 1538607113838},
 {'level': 'INFO',
  'message': '{"message":{"method":"Network.requestWillBeSent","params":{"documentURL":"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52633697/selenium-python-how-to-capture-network-traffics-response","frameId":"C2D13BD13CF743B6D0695B35E9CC935C","hasUserGesture":false,"initiator":{"type":"other"},"loaderId":"5331BFDC4F466FCED920CFC9F033D2EC","request":{"headers":{"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":"1","User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36"},"initialPriority":"VeryHigh","method":"GET","mixedContentType":"none","referrerPolicy":"no-referrer-when-downgrade","url":"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52633697/selenium-python-how-to-capture-network-traffics-response"},"requestId":"5331BFDC4F466FCED920CFC9F033D2EC","timestamp":104499.729,"type":"Document","wallTime":1538607113.838206}},"webview":"C2D13BD13CF743B6D0695B35E9CC935C"}',
  'timestamp': 1538607113839},...}
```

You need to enable logging using `DesiredCapabilities`, and then you can parse it using python’s `JSON` module:

```
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
caps['loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'ALL'}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps)
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55171235/view-list-of-element-sources-with-selenium/55171555#55171555’)

def process_browser_log_entry(entry):
    response = json.loads(entry['message'])['message']
    return response

browser_log = driver.get_log('performance') 
events = [process_browser_log_entry(entry) for entry in browser_log]
events = [event for event in events if 'Network.response' in event['method']]
```

That’s the (unfortunately) the only way I’ve ever found to get them anyway.