# AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'execute_cdp_cmd'

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium4

I am trying to set geolocation based on this documentation: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/support_packages/chrome_devtools/

**I am using selenium==4.0.0b2**

I am running **remote webdriver** instead of local, and I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'execute_cdp_cmd'
```

This is my sample code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor='http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
)
    Map_coordinates = dict({
            "latitude": 21.841,
            "longitude": -97.948,
            "accuracy": 100
        })

print(Map_coordinates)
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Emulation.setGeolocationOverride", Map_coordinates)

driver.get('http://www.google.com/')
time.sleep(50)
```

What am I missing??

Comment: How do you declare driver?

Comment: That is how I declare the driver

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem. But I am using is VB.NET at Visual Studio cannot find any Chrome Devtool.
And at the end I found a nuget that is
https://github.com/ToCSharp/AsyncChromeDriver
You can try to look at.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was following example from [Selenium - python. how to capture network traffic's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52633697/selenium-python-how-to-capture-network-traffics-response) and got it working "python3 script.py". After numerous executions started seeing this error due to wrong python version used. If someone has the same error it can happen if system loads python3.6 instead of python3.9 so I needed to specify exact python version.