# Python requests get all other requests after sending post

Tags: python, web-scraping, request

I am logging in into a website with python request by sending a post with required data.
I am trying to get other http requests after sending the previous http post.
Is there a way to do it?

If I log in manually in browser I can see all other requests that are being sent after logging in (which is the first POST in screenshot), I want to grab them all (the ones marked with green marker):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when you login a new html side is responded to your web browser.
During the rendering of this site some files like images or javascript are requested from the server side. With selenium you can automate user interactions with a web browser and log the traffic like described in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52633697/selenium-python-how-to-capture-network-traffics-response).